# Equality constraints in trait in Rust. Variant with Into<T> trait

Tags: rust, iterator, constraints, traits

I want the ToKeyIter::Item be equal to ToKeyIter::KeyIter::Item as KeyIter should implement Iterator trait. I couldn't do it because with constraint equality in where clause. That's why I decided to use trait Into.

```
pub trait ToKeyIter {
    type Item: Clone + Hash + Eq;
    type KeyIter<'b>: Iterator where Self: 'b, <Self::KeyIter<'b> as Iterator>::Item: Into<Self::Item>;
    fn key_iter<'a> (&'a self) -> Self::KeyIter<'a> 
    where <Self::KeyIter<'a> as Iterator>::Item: Into<Self::Item>;
}
```

The trait itself compiles, but when I try to impl it for str or String, the compiler fails with "overflow evaluating the requirement".

```
impl ToKeyIter for str {
    type Item = char;
    type KeyIter<'a> = Chars<'a>;

    fn key_iter<'a> (&'a self) -> Chars<'a> {
        self.chars()
    }
}


impl ToKeyIter for String {
    type Item = char;
    type KeyIter<'a> = Chars<'a>;
    
    fn key_iter<'a> (&'a self) -> Chars<'a> {
        self.chars()
    }
}
```

If you can tell how to write something like this

```
Key::Item == Key::KeyIter::Item
```

it will be great. But also I want to know what I should do to have correct impl for str and String with Into trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `Iterate<Item=Self::Item>` to obtain what you want. See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=365ca1b963140a017473588ec9a3cfcc) for a live version of this:

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

use std::hash::Hash;
use std::str::Chars;

pub trait ToKeyIter {
    type Item: Clone + Hash + Eq;
    type KeyIter<'a>: Iterator<Item=Self::Item>
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn key_iter<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::KeyIter<'a>;
}

impl ToKeyIter for str {
    type Item = char;
    type KeyIter<'a> = Chars<'a>;

    fn key_iter<'a> (&'a self) -> Chars<'a> {
        self.chars()
    }
}
impl ToKeyIter for String {
    type Item = char;
    type KeyIter<'a> = Chars<'a>;
    
    fn key_iter<'a> (&'a self) -> Chars<'a> {
        self.chars()
    }
}
```